# How to do these in weka: cross validation + imbalanced data + feature selection

Tags: machine-learning, weka, cross-validation, feature-selection, imbalanced-data

I have an imbalanced dataset (classification dataset).

By using Weka platform, I want to apply these techniques: cross validation, balancing the training folds, feature selection

So, I did the following (From *Classify* tab):

1. I chose 10-fold cross-validation technique.
2. I chose *FilteredClassifier*, and edited its proprieties by:

- choosing a classifier.
- choosing the filter *Multifilter*, and editing its proprieties by adding two filters:

  - *SMOTE* as the first filter.
  - *AttributeSelection* as the second filter.

Is my work correct?

Comment: That approach is fine.

Comment: What do you think about using FilteredAttributeEval insted of Multifilter? Is it correct?

Comment: You can use the meta-classifier AttributeSelectedClassifier in conjunction with FilteredAttributeEval/FilteredSubsetEval (and SMOTE as your filter). But be aware that FilteredAttributeEval only reorders the attributes (using the attributes' merit). Only with FilteredSubsetEval you will actually get a new subset of attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The preprocess panel or feature selection tab should only be used to explore the data (hence the name *Weka Explorer*).

For incorporating preprocessing for addressing balancing training data or selecting attributes, use Weka's meta classifiers (you can nest them):

- balancing: FilteredClassifier with SMOTE
- feature selection: AttributeSelectedClassifier with your choice of search/evaluation and base classifier

Balancing is the outermost classifier, which uses the feature selection classifier as its classifier.

You can use the *Weka Experimenter* for comparing various setups and obtain statistical significance results. See the Weka manual PDF for details.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply ...... I edited my question and modified my method ....... hope to read your comment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For Weka Experimenter ..... My dataset has a class attribute which is the second column (not the last one as usual) ...... So, when I use (Weka Experimenter) the error message comes out (Class attribute is not nominal) because the last attribute is numeric ..... And I do not know how to choose the class attribute (as I do in Preprocess & Classify tabs)

Comment: No. The ARFF format doesn't allow you to specify which attribute is the class attribute. You can save your datasets as XRFF from the Explorer's Preprocess tab after selecting the correct attribute as class attribute. Otherwise, you will need to reorder your datasets using the [Reorder](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/Reorder.html) filter.